# Git Push Successful, No Actual Files in Targeted Directories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, git

I have a test and prod server, both running Ubuntu 20.04 with virtuamin 7 control panel, LAMP and git.

**Problem:**
My current git push configs seem correct.  I get no errors at all... but at last, the pushed files do not actually appear in the targeted directories, so I am confused.

I think that the `--work-tree` git flag gets ignored, so pushed files never get put in the correct place

in my `/home/username/public_html/production-site.git/hooks/push-receiver.sh` bash script I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Set Receiving & Working directories
git --work-tree=/home/username/public_html --git-dir=/home/username/public_html/production-site.git checkout -f
```

executable

```
username@admin:~/public_html/production-site.git$ stat hooks/push-receiver.sh
  File: hooks/push-receiver.sh
  Size: 165         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd04h/64772d    Inode: 1970021     Links: 1
Access: (0775/-rwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1051/username)   Gid: ( 1028/username)
Access: 2022-09-10 17:51:41.904111692 +0800
Modify: 2022-09-10 17:49:24.957850296 +0800
Change: 2022-09-10 17:49:37.122051612 +0800
 Birth: -
```

no errors on test side:

```
$ git remote -v
prodsite    username@XXX.YY.XX.YY:public_html/production-site.git (fetch)
prodsite    username@XXX.YY.XX.YY:public_html/production-site.git (push)
```

```
Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Enumerating objects: 8, done.
Counting objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 551 bytes | 551.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To XXX.YY.XX.YY:/home/username/public_html/production-site.git
   f251e56..9e7f4f3  master -> master
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'prodsite'.
```

Net result... no actual files in targeted directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hook called `push-receiver`. That also means there is no hook called `push-receiver.sh`: Your file must have the exact hook name, without any extension. (The only exception are `.exe` files on Windows.)

You can learn about available hooks [in the githooks man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks). There’s one that is pretty much exactly for your use case: `push-to-checkout`. However, I don’t think it will work on a bare repository. You should check out `post-update` and `post-receive`.

Comment: Thx... rookie error...  changed name to 'post-receive' everything works perfectly